# Error 1005 when trying to create a table with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create some tables that represent a fantasy football league, which itself contains teams, which itself contains picked players, who are players with stats. I have a very basic draft right now and I'm trying to get my foreign keys working, however, I keep getting this error when I try and add in the key:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 19: Can't create table 'football_db.PickedPlayers' (errno: 150)
```

I have of course googled around a bit and the problem has, as that error message indicates, something to do with my foreign keys on that table.

Can I not add multiple sets of foreign keys? or is it the types of foreign keys I chose? Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE football_db.Leagues
    (league_id INT NOT NULL,
     league_name VARCHAR(100),
     PRIMARY KEY (league_id))
    ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE football_db.Teams
    (league_id INT NOT NULL,
     team_id INT NOT NULL,
     team_name VARCHAR(100),
     PRIMARY KEY (league_id,team_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (league_id) REFERENCES Leagues(league_id))
    ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE football_db.PickedPlayers
    (league_id INT NOT NULL,
     team_id INT NOT NULL,
     player_id INT NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (player_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (league_id,team_id) REFERENCES Teams(league_id,team_id),
     FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES Players(player_id))
    ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE football_db.Players
    (player_id INT NOT NULL,
     player_name VARCHAR(50),
     position VARCHAR(10),
     is_free_agent BOOL,
     PRIMARY KEY (player_id))
    ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I was typing this up I figured out the problem myself. Figured I'll at least post my solution here since other people might run in to the same (really stupid and noobish) problem.

The problem was that I was creating the `PickedPlayers` table before `Players` and so it had no idea what foreign key from `Players` it was supposed to be referencing since it didn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

you are giving referense to table `players` before creating this table , just move creating table `CREATE TABLE football_db.PickedPlayers` in last position like that:

```
 CREATE TABLE Leagues
(league_id INT NOT NULL,
 league_name VARCHAR(100),
 PRIMARY KEY (league_id))
ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE Teams
(league_id INT NOT NULL,
 team_id INT NOT NULL,
 team_name VARCHAR(100),
 PRIMARY KEY (league_id,team_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (league_id) REFERENCES Leagues(league_id))
ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE Players
(player_id INT NOT NULL,
 player_name VARCHAR(50),
 position VARCHAR(10),
 is_free_agent BOOL,
 PRIMARY KEY (player_id))
ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE PickedPlayers
(league_id INT NOT NULL,
 team_id INT NOT NULL,
 player_id INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (player_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (league_id,team_id) REFERENCES Teams(league_id,team_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES Players(player_id))
ENGINE=INNODB;
```

[**Live working demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8936a/1)